# Rails model design for has_many with filter model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Client` model that `has_many :orders` but each order also `belongs_to :order_type`. The `OrderType` here is used as filter table basically since each order has a set of common attributes like `:category, :size, :date` and has a few thousand entries so it made sense to me to keep this in a separate model as opposed to keeping those information on every individual order entry.

I am a little confused as to how to setup the associations and what where I need a join table so I can basically query something like this:

```
c = Client.find(x)
order_conditions = {date: "2016-01-01".."2016-01-31", category: "x")
```

How do I need to setup the models and associatons / join tables so I can get all the orders that match a certain list of OrderType conditions for a given client?

It seems like I need a multiple join somewhere according to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) `12.1.3 Joining Multiple Associations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
def Client
  has_many :orders
end

def Order
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :order_type
end

def OrderType
  has_many :orders
end


# To query
client.orders.joins(:order_type).where(order_types: { date: date })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not make

OrderType belong_to :order

And
Order has_one :order_type

Then you can find all orders with matching order type. (Though I'd probably just include order_type in the order database)

I'm rather a novice so apologies if this is nonsense and please delete :)